# How check in PHP is my string $a at postion $i is string $b

Tags: php

How check in PHP is my string $a at postion $i is string $b

```
 $a = "Ha me duck who,garage?!"
 $b = "duck"
 $i = 7;
 echo function($a,$b,$i); // will return true, but for other $i false
```

Comment: specifically `return ( $i == strpos($a, $b ) )`    http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: it won't work if there are two occurences of "duck" in the string and I am checking for the second one

Comment: one way, $curIndex = 0;. put the `strpos` search in a `while ( $curIndex = strpos(..., $curIndex) !== false) loop`. And store and used the index returned to keep a list a found matches. Use any or all of the found matches as required

Comment: Demonstration of the technique:  https://eval.in/614796. It is a list  of the `$i` in the `$a`. :) Please try to use useful variable names in your code. i.e. `$b ==> $needle`, `$a ==> $haystack` and `$i => $searchStartPos`. Yes, a lot of typing but easy to understand - now and later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to check at multiple occurrences, this soln makes a substring at expected index (with length of needle) and checks if the strings match.

```
<? php
$a = "Ha me duck who,garage, duck?!";
$b = "duck";
$i = 23;
var_dump(chk($a, $b, $i));
function chk($a, $b, $i) {
  return substr($a, $i, strlen($b)) === $b;
}
```

Comment: it won't work if there are two occurences of "duck" in the string and I am checking for the second one

Comment: Ya, thanks, I not connet Internet at 30.07, so answer now.

Comment: @youmound no worries, but the soln worked for you? if so accept it.